# Advise on abstraction

Tags: c#, abstraction

I am working on some code whereby I have an abstract class that has a few core properties and a Run(int index) method. I then create new types that inherit this. These new types can have multiple methods that can be called according to the index passed in.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void Run(int index);
}


public class Class1 : BaseClass
{

    public override void Run(int index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            MethodA(); 
        }
        else if (index == 1)
        {
            MethodB();
        }
    }

    private void MethodA()
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    private void MethodB()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering is there a better way to do this. These types and methods would be called from a UI,  - a menu click for example.  So I might have a class1 and a class2. Class1 might have 3 methods so I could call run(0) ... run(2) on it. Class2 might just have one internal method so I would just call run(0).  Maybe I would need to keep a collection of ints with each class I guess as a map to methods. Might also have to add a string to this collection to hold a friendly name for menu items etc..

Can you think of a way to implement this type of mapping while maintaining as much abstraction as possible? Is there a better way to go about this that my current idea?

Comment: Question seem to be "I invented Windows message loop... Now what?" - I'd recommend to skip these initial painful versions and go straight to some more recent eventing mechanism with strongly typed events...

Answer (score 1):

One way:

You could use an interface instead:

```
public interface IRunnableSomething {
    void Run();
}

public class MyRunnableA :IRunnableSomething  
{
    public void Run() {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class MyRunnableB :IRunnableSomething 
{
    public void Run() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Then in your main class...

```
public override void Run(IRunnable runnable)
{
    runnable.Run();
}
```

Example of calling it:

```
myInstanceOfMainClass.Run(new MyRunnableA());
```

This seems fitting, since you already know what `index` you were passing in with your original version. This just moves it from `int` based to `interface` based (less code too in the end).

Comment: I think you forgot to include `: IRunnableSomething` to each of the classes.

Comment: I did indeed. The perils of typing straight into the browser! :)

Comment: Many thanks for the reply but you've lost me. Whats the point of the interface ?  and lets say class MyRunnableB  has 4 methods that I might want to run, I now have to create types for each ?  What happens if I want to extend the project with plugins for example ?

Comment: @user2026382 That is generally good information to include in your question. This response seems perfectly fitting for your original question.. but not if you plan on extending it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain a bit further so.  Here's a slightly more verbose version of what I am trying to do. You can see here that my abstract class has the list of indexes for pointing at the right method in derived classes, and you can see where I am loading types and creating menu items in a UI. I am using this ItemPointer list and passing around ItemPointers to tag properties etc. It all feels a bit wrong somehow.

I wish for the whole thing to be extensible. I might want to add a Class2, Class3 etc all inheriting BaseClass. I might also want to create plugins using BaseClass. Any derived class will have at least one but runable method but will likely have many. So Class1 here is just an example. Does this help explain myself?  please go easy on me, I'm learning and that's why I am asking here.

Is what I'm doing here awful?  or is it ok?  or is there a better way? I guess that's my question. If there is a better way, I'd really appreciate an example.  Many thanks to all for the help. It is much appreciated.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public List<ItemPointer> ItemPointers = new List<ItemPointer>();
    public abstract void Run(int index);
}



public class ItemPointer
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string ClassType { get; set; }
    public string UIDescription { get; set; }
}



public class Class1 : BaseClass
{
    public Class1()
    {
        ItemPointers.Add(new ItemPointer { Index = 0, ClassType = this.GetType().Name,  UIDescription = "MethodA Description" });
        ItemPointers.Add(new ItemPointer { Index = 1, ClassType = this.GetType().Name,  UIDescription = "MethodB Description" });
    }

    public override void Run(int index)
    {            
        if (index == 0)
        {
            MethodA();
        }
        else if (index == 1)
        {
            MethodB();
        }
    }

    private void MethodA()
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    private void MethodB()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}



public class UIForm
{
    private List<BaseClass> _baseClasses;

    //Formload events load all baseclass types (including plugins via reflection during form init etc. Then call loadUIitems

    private void LoadUIItems()
    {
        foreach (BaseClass bc in _baseClasses)
        {
            foreach (var p in bc.ItemPointers)
            {
                ToolStripMenuItem t = new ToolStripMenuItem(p.UIDescription);
                t.Click += new EventHandler(WorkerMenu_Click);
                t.Tag = p;
                actionsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(t);  
            }
        }
    }



    void WorkerMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem t = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
        ItemPointer p = (ItemPointer)t.Tag;

        foreach (BaseClass bc in _baseClasses)
        {
            if (bc.GetType().Name == p.ClassType)
            {
                bc.Run(p.Index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your position I might be inclined to try do something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new Class1();
    var b = new Class2();

    try
    {           
        a.Run("Foo");
        b.Run("Bar", "Yoda");
        b.Run("Bat"); // throws exception
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
    }
}

class Base
{
    public void Run(string commandName, params object[] args)
    {
        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod(commandName);
        if(method != null)
            method.Invoke(this, args);
        else
            throw new Exception("the command " + commandName + " does not exist on " + this.GetType().Name);
    }
}

class Class1 : Base
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("I am foo");
    }
}

class Class2 : Base
{
    public void Bar(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("I am {0}", str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
I am foo
I am Yoda
the command Bat does not exist on Class2
```